# Is it possible to delete all Facebook app posts without removing the app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-apps

I have a lot apps and websites I'm connected to with my Facebook account.

In the past, it was the common thing that an app would post on your wall everything (it's set to private, but still exist).

I want to delete all this irrelevant content produced by those apps, but not remove them from Facebook, cause it will delete all the data and probably my user on this sites (which is not what I want).

Is this possible?
Of course, without going one by one and removing every post.

Comment: Downvoter - may explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like these, deleting activity without deleting all posts one by one, are being asked regularly, and Facebook does not offer an automated solution for it. (I suppose they have their reasons not to.)

There are third-party scripts that will allow you to, such as the [Social Book Post Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/social-book-post-manager/ljfidlkcmdmmibngdfikhffffdmphjae) Chrome extension. I have tested it with moderate results. What it does is deleting your activity as you would do manually, but via a script so you have your hands free. The main problem appears to be that it may go too fast, resulting in some deletion requests not being processed. That's why the extension has a 'Speed' setting. The extension is not excellent and there appear to be mixed reviews, but it should help you further.